# Ignore phone's output while recording nativescript

Tags: audio, nativescript, recording

I am trying to record over an existing audio file in nativescript core (js), the problem is that while I record, the output contains the audio file played through the phone speakers as well. Is there a way to ignore the output of the phone while recording?

Comment: Try passing `source` as `1` in the options (`.start({source: 1})`

Comment: @Manoj Are you talking about the nativescript-audio plugin? (TNSRecorder)

Comment: yes, thats correct. If you are not using that, please explain further what you are doing.